# UIView z-index transparency

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have stacked views with the same frame on top of each other and they are all children of the same view.
The problem is that I use pan gesture to move them off the stack and while doing so the view under the view on top is completely transparent though I have set its alpha.
How to make the views beneath visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be completely unrelated. I instantiated the view from xib twice and for some reason this caused my issue.